# VLC stream webcam video with audio

Tags: audio, vlc

Using Linux Mint 18.1 32bit, Logitech pro 9000, vlc 2.2.2

I have searched many sites for tips and have found many to record the video, but none that come close to streaming or recording both the video and the audio.

The closest was from [Trouble getting VLC to record from the webcam via command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58526/trouble-getting-vlc-to-record-from-the-webcam-via-command-line). This streams the video but does not play the audio.

```
cvlc v4l2:// :input-slave=alsa:// :v4l-vdev="/dev/video0" :v4l-norm=3 \
  :v4l-frequency=-1 :v4l-caching=300 :v4l-chroma="" :v4l-fps=-1.000000 \
  :v4l-samplerate=44100 :v4l-channel=0 :v4l-tuner=-1 :v4l-audio=-1 :v4l-stereo \
  :v4l-width=480 :v4l-height=360 :v4l-brightness=-1 :v4l-colour=-1 :v4l-hue=-1 \
  :v4l-contrast=-1 :no-v4l-mjpeg :v4l-decimation=1 :v4l-quality=100 \
  --sout="#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=2000,fps=12,scale=0.67,acodec=vorb,ab=90,channels=1,samplerate=44100}:standard{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=output.ogg}"
```

How would the command be modified to play video and audio?

**Edit**

Pulseaudio is running:

```
$ ps axu | grep pulse
bill 1553 0.0 0.5 176268 10456 ? S<l 15:15 0:02 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

List of audio devices:

```
$ arecord -l **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC9200 Analog [STAC9200 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Q9000 [QuickCam Pro 9000], device 0:
  USB Audio [USB Audio] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Do you want to *stream* audio and video (make it available for possibly multiple clients on your LAN), or *record* audio and video together from webcam and ALSA? These are very different things ... And to record audio: Do you run Pulseaudio? Have you tried recording the audio alone? Did it work?

Comment: My plan is to record audio and video together from webcam and ALSA. With ALSA I guess. Do not know about Pulseaudio. Will try recording audio alone later today or early tomorrow.

Comment: Please run `ps axu | grep pulse`, look if there's a `pulseaudio` process running, and edit the question. You can use `arecord` to test recording with ALSA, and `arecord -l` to list your devices.

Comment: Tried using directions from ourpcsolutions.blogspot.com and stackoverflow,com without success on just audio and video with audio. Here is results  ~ $ ps axu | grep pulse
bill      1553  0.0  0.5 176268 10456 ?        S<l  15:15   0:02 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
bill      4096  0.0  0.0   5112   776 pts/0    S+   16:03   0:00 grep --color=auto pulse
Have no idea what this means. Using Logitech pro 9000 device.

Comment: Did fresh install of Audio Recorder. Made a test recording and it played OK.

Comment: $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC9200 Analog [STAC9200 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Q9000 [QuickCam Pro 9000], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: Please **edit** the question with additional information, don't put it in the comments. Indent by four spaces for proper formatting. (I just did that for you).

Answer (score 2):

Quick review of Linux audio: Today, basically all device drivers are part of ALSA. ALSA can be used on its own, but basically all distros run Pulseaudio on top, which offers a better experience in some respects. Pulseaudio includes a compatibility layer that allows old ALSA-only applications to use Pulseaudio by pretending it is an ALSA device (called `pulse`), while Pulseaudio in turn uses the device drivers of ALSA.

Your system is like this, and you have two audio devices (the internal device and the camera).

So what happens when you use `--input-slave=alsa://` is that vlc uses the compatibility layer, which accesses Pulseaudio, which guesses what device you want and gives you the first device, which is the internal device and not the webcam. Thus, no sound.

You can use `pavucontrol` (or `pacmd` or `pactl` if you don't have a GUI) while recording to change where `vlc` records from. Depending on your Pulseaudio setup, this choice will usually be remembered next time, so you need to only do it once.

Or even better, tell vlc to use Pulseaudio in the first place.
I couldn't quickly find proper documentation on `--input-slave` for vlc, but the google results suggest `--input-slave=pulse` does work, and very likely there's some `--input-slave=pulse://pulseaudio_source_name` syntax that actually allows you to specify the correct card (called "sound source" in Pulseaudio).

**Edit**

The [source code](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/master/modules/access/pulse.c) says the format is `pulse://SOURCE`, without specifying details, so I guess you can do

```
pactl list short sources
```

and then specify something like `pulse://alsa_input.usb-XXX-YYY` with whatever your Pulseaudio source name is. Again, you can use `pavucontrol` to reassign the source, if necessary.

Comment: Tried these 2 with out success.                                                            input-slave=pulse://alsa_input.usb-046d:0990 
 --input-slave=pulse
Will continue my quest and will keep you informed.                                    Thank for all you did.

Comment: So try first to change the source with `pavucontrol`, or `pacmd move-source-output <index> <source>` if you have to use the command line (use `pamcd list` etc. to figure out what is what).

Comment: Will have to wait until Saturday. Linux user group meeting. Will need some help with this.  Will keep you posted. Thanks again.